# i18n as JSON field in MySQL vs separate table

Tags: mysql

Performance wise, what is the best DB structure for i18n for a table that stores a few varchar fields that will need to be translated into multiple languages:

JSON field with array of key (lang code), values

or

A sparse table with relationship to original table, row and key

The field will be queried using LIKE's

Comment: Are you using Cloud tech?  If so, you should consider using dynamodb or some other form of nosql to store your JSON fields.  If nosql isn't an option, it's easier but less performant to use JSON columns in mysql.  If you can store the JSON as representative table of sql columns, you should do that if you care about performance and are accessing this data millions or billions of times a day.  

So it's really a matter of preference.  It's easier for JSON datatype but it's more performant if you create a table and parse out the JSON into sql columns.

Comment: Leading wildcard on the LIKEs?  If so, that is always a slow table scan.  Please provide the alternate CREATE TABLEs and SELECTs; some things in your question are vague;.